# How can I improve code completion on Rust variables with an inferred type?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

I'm using VS Code 1.33.1 and the Rust (RLS) extension. If I explicitly type my variables I get nice completions like [image: this]

When they're not explicitly typed, it looks like [image: this]

Which is pretty crippling for inline stuff e.g.:
[image] and also makes it basically impossible (as far as I know?) to get completion for things like complex (or even simple?) `map` calls like `(0..1).map(|x| x)`, which maps which cannot be named (something like `std::iter::Map<std::ops::Range<{integer}>, [closure@src\main.rs:3:32: 3:37]>`)

In addition, while I can get nice completions if I've fully typed out a function, for e.g. hovering on the `any` below:

[image]

It looks decidedly less nice if I'm mid-way through building it, for example:

[image]

And to be frank, that's when I want it the most. I can appreciate it might not be possible to show ALL completions as due to the trait nature this can be overwhelming, but I thought perhaps it could narrow things down once I'd typed `any`.

I guess mainly I just want to check is this the state of completions in VS Code at the moment and that I haven't misconfigured something.